# DialogFragment not rendering style correctly

Tags: android, android-layout, actionbarsherlock

I am attempting to style a DialogFragment and, despite extensive research within SO, developer.android and elsewhere, it's just not working right.

I am sure that I have applied everything correctly; in my DialogFragment onCreateDialog, I am putting:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(new ContextThemeWrapper(getActivity(), R.style.FibroDialog));
```

and in values/styles.xml, I have:

```
<style name="FibroDialog" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/panel_background</item>
</style>
```

and in values-v14/styles.xml, I have:

```
<style name="FibroDialog" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/panel_background</item>
</style>
```

If I run that, I get the top row of dialogs in the image below, where nothing has changed at all, but I would expect the window to use my panel_background drawable. If I change windowBackground to background, I get the bottom row of dialogs in the image below, where it all goes wrong.

[image]

So how do I change this, so the entire dialogs have the purple background? I know I can use the layoutInflator and put a background colour in the layout, but that only does the middle bit.

I don't know if this is of *any* relevance, but the DialogFragment is launched from a SherlockFragment